# grammar - lack or with low

Tags: grammaticality-in-context

I would greatly appreciated if someone could gave me some insight on this phrase construction

Wich one is correct?

"these techniques are difficult and lack sensitivity"

Or

"these techniques are difficult and with low sensitivity"

Thank you

Comment: If the difficulty is because of the low sensitivity: "These techniques are made difficult by low sensitivity." Else your first sentence most clearly expresses that the technique has two flaws: difficulty and low sensitivity.

Comment: What kind of sensitivity are we talking about? Can you give us more context about what you want to say and what you want it to mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)

> these techniques are difficult and lack sensitivity

I think this is OK. This is saying:

> these techniques are difficult **AND** these techniques lack sensitivity

Each phrase by itself can stand alone and have the same structure.

2)

> these techniques are difficult and with low sensitivity

I think this is not so good.  This is saying:

> these techniques are difficult **AND** these techniques are with low sensitivity

in this case

> these techniques are with low sensitivity

does not really make sense to me.

I won't say it is technically wrong, but it makes more sense to me as:

> these techniques are difficult and *have* low sensitivity

Comment: You're severely misstating the principle. In the example "Fred and John have dogs and cats." it sounds like you are suggesting that "cats" has no verb so this is a non-grammatical sentence.

Comment: @leoger  Sorry I was only referring to this example, so probably I should just leave out any rule. In any case I read my answer and rewrote it to hopefully make more sense. I left out that the second phrase is wrong, but I don't think its so good